# Power BI Table Visualization show percentage of True as total in boolean column

Tags: powerbi, boolean, percentage

I have a bunch of student names in a table visualization with another column containing booleans.

I would like to display the percentage of True values as the total for this boolean column so it would look something like:

True

True

False

True

True

80%

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to modelling tab and change your data type from True/False to text. by doing so, the true value would be 1 and false value 0 and you can use sum function to get percentage of True values.
[image]
create following measures to get true and false measures:

```
T = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'your_table' ), FILTER ( 'your_table', 'your_table'[true_boolean]= "1" )) 

F = CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'your_table' ), FILTER ( 'your_table', 'your_table'[false_boolean]= "0" ))
```

The following measure will give you the percentage of values

```
True = DIVIDE([T],COUNTROWS('your_table') ) 

False= DIVIDE([F],COUNTROWS('your_table') )
```

or you can use straightforward measures like

```
True = DIVIDE(CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'your_table' ), FILTER ( 'your_table', 'your_table'[true_boolean]= "1" )),COUNTROWS('your_table') ) 


False = DIVIDE(CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'your_table' ), FILTER ( 'your_table', 'your_table'[false_boolean]= "0" )),COUNTROWS('your_table') )
```

However you should go to modelling tab and change the True and False measures to decimal with at least 4 decimal places.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. I followed your instructions and could see that it the total showed the sum of the 1s and 0s. However, I can't get it to display as a percentage. If I do 'show value as percent of grand total', it shows 100% and changes all of the 1s to 0.62% (there are 161 1s out of 221 rows). I want to leave the 1s as they are and show the total as 72.9%. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: Sorry - I'm new to all of this. Can you tell me step-by-step how to do this, assuming I know nothing. Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks but I get "The end of the input was reached"

Comment: I have edited my anwer look at it

Comment: Thanks - I really appreciate your help.  I'll give it a go.

Comment: you can use The first four formulas or simply The last two formulas

Comment: Did it worked in your issue?

Comment: Yes thanks. Much appreciated